# How do I connect a homebrew antenna using RX-8 to a Yaesu FT-70DR (SMA)?

Tags: antenna, diy, coaxial-cable, yaesu, connectors

I made an 2m / 70cm tape measure antenna using RG-8 coax. That part was quite a bit of fun and went fine. But when I tried to connect the coax to my Yaesu FT-70DR, the copper core of the RG-8 was too thick to fit into the SMA adapter. How do I connect my antenna to my HT? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either find an adapter that will work or cut the end off the RG-8 and solder on the proper connector.

You could also find an SMA cable and replace the RG-8 entirely.

Comment: Hello Marshall, and welcome to this site! :-)

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, Marshall. I ended up switch cables to RG-6 and everything worked great. Heard the packet traffic off the ISS beacon first time out of the garage.